# Applying weak form

Tags: boundary-conditions, computational-physics, computational-geometry

I have two dimensional equation and I want to solve it using Finite Element Methods.
$$ \nabla . (\alpha(x,y)\nabla u(x,y)) + \dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y}+u(x,y)=f(x,y)$$
$$\alpha(x,y)\dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial n}=g(x,y),  for (x,y)\in \partial\Omega$$
To obtain its weak form, I multiplied the equation with a residual function $w$. And applied the vector identity shown below.
$$\nabla.(b\vec{A})=\nabla b.\vec{A}+b\nabla . \vec{A}$$ 
One of the terms is come out as shown below.
$$\int_{\partial\Omega} w\nabla g(x,y).\vec{n} dl $$
This term corresponds to a boundary condition. How should I derive the rest of the equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont expand the divergence term, apply integration by parts without doing this
$$
\int_\Omega w \nabla\cdot(\alpha\nabla u) dx = - \int_\Omega \alpha \nabla u \cdot \nabla w dx + \int_{\partial\Omega} w \alpha \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}ds
$$
In your notation, define a vector field
$$
\vec{A} = \alpha \nabla u
$$
and then do the integration by parts on
$$
\int_\Omega w \nabla\cdot\vec{A} dx
$$
Since
$$
w \nabla\cdot\vec{A} = \nabla\cdot(w\vec{A}) - \vec{A} \cdot \nabla w
$$
You get
$$
\int_\Omega w \nabla\cdot\vec{A} dx = \int_{\partial\Omega} w \vec{A}\cdot\vec{n} ds - \int_\Omega \vec{A} \cdot \nabla w dx
$$
which is the first equation above. Using your boundary condition, it becomes
$$
\int_\Omega w \nabla\cdot(\alpha\nabla u) dx = - \int_\Omega \alpha \nabla u \cdot \nabla w dx + \int_{\partial\Omega} w g ds
$$

Comment: Shouldn't the first equation be $
\int_\Omega w \nabla\cdot(\alpha\nabla u) ds = - \int_\Omega \alpha \nabla u \cdot \nabla w ds + \int_{\partial\Omega} w \alpha \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}dl
$ ? @cfdlab

Comment: On the other hand, how did you find the $\int_{\partial\Omega} w \vec{A}\cdot\vec{n} ds$ term? @cfdlab

Comment: It is divergence theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem. Replace $ds=dl$ to get your notation. I used $dx$ for domain integration and $ds$ for surface integration.